# Tomcat7, Log4j Container and WebApp level configuration

Tags: tomcat, solr, log4j, tomcat7

I have a tomcat installation with `CATALINA_HOME` and `CATALINA_BASE` at the same location. This tomcat only hosts a solr instance.

First thing I wanted to do was to generate log4j logging to a separate file for solr, let's say at `${catalina.base}/logs/solr.log`, which I managed to do by adding log4j.properties in `${CATALINA_HOME}/webapps/solr/WEB-INF/classes/`.

Then I wanted to configure tomcat itself to generate log4j output and followed the apache [guide](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html) for log4j. This worked for catalina but seems that overwrite my previous configuration for solr and the seperate file it was logging, doesn't log anymore.

I tried to delete the `WEB-INF/classes` directory and copy the appender to the tomcat log4j file and also added this `log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/solr] =INFO, SOLR` at the end but still I cannot get the separate file logging for solr itself.

Is this happening because of the order of the class loading hierarchy? And if yes why? It normally should be possible to overwrite configuration on a lower level.

Is there another possible way to have separate log4j configuration for a webapp?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve my own problem, so here is the answer if someone will need it.

To enable log4j for solr you need to download and copy under `webapps/solr/WEB-INF/lib` the following jars `slf4j-log4j12-1.7.6.jar`, `slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar` and `log4j-1.2.17.jar` and **remove** any `slf4j-jdk` jars if existent. Then add your `log4j.properties` file under `webapps/solr/WEB-INF/classes` and create directory `classes` if it doesn't exist.
In my case I was missing the `slf4j` jars and it was loading the jars from the tomcat container which in turn didn't resolve the `classes/log4j.properties`. Once adding them to solr the correct `log4j.properties` was resolved.

For the tomcat log4j configuration I followed the log4j section [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html)

If you want to write from solr to `catalina.out` and a separate file at the same time just add two appenders in the `classes/log4j.properties`.

I didn't manage to configure a log4j appender to control the log4j output of a specific webapp(in my case solr) from the tomcats `log4j.properties` using `log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/solr] =INFO, SOLR`. So if someone has experience with this configuration, would be nice to know the how to.